# call a function class php

Tags: php, class, function, return

I created a class that has 2 functions that deal with the connection to the database and to make a questy. One of these calls the other.
This is my code, but it gives me error .... sure something wrong in calling the function.
Can anyone help me?

```
class DB{

public function connect(){
    session_start();
    include_once('libs/Smarty.class.php');
    $smarty = new Smarty();
    $smarty->setTemplateDir('templates/');
    $smarty->setCompileDir('templates_c/');
    $smarty->setConfigDir('configs/');
    $smarty->setCacheDir('cache/');

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $pass = "pass";
    $tablename = "table";

    return $connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
    mysql_select_db($tablename, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
}

public function do_query($query){
    echo DB::connect();
     if(mysql_query($query,DB::connect())){
         $message="Annuncio inserito correttamente!!";
         echo $message;
     }else{
         $message="Error insert data into DB: ";
         echo $message. mysql_error();
     }
}
```

}

Comment: try self::connect if  you use static class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your return the $connect ... but you might want to return the mysql_select_db

```
$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
return mysql_select_db($tablename, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
```

EDIT:

I was answering to "sure something is wrong ..." as it was an obvious mistake that the last statement isn't executed.

But if you want to use the connect you need to return it, sure!

```
$connect = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
mysql_select_db($tablename, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
return $connect;
```

Comment: mysql_select_db doesn't return connection

Comment: @DevZer0, he was correcting a mistake that OP had. OP was returning the connection and it was never getting the chance to select the database.

Comment: it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: It allows the function `connect()` to select the database. It's not bailing on the mysql connection anymore...

Comment: And it doesn't matter if mysql_select_db returns a stream or not. It doesn't need to. It's a command, not a connection. It will return True/false.

Comment: tell me how does `if(mysql_query($query,DB::connect())){` line work with your code ?

Comment: @conceptdeluxe can you ask your buddy to upvote his downvote, or if you can upvote me too would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

there is some design errors, your template logic should be outside of database connection method. Apart from that following changes needs to be made

```
 class DB {

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $pass = "pass";
    private $tablename = "table";
    private $con = null; //change here

public function connect(){
    $this->con = $connect = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass); change here
    mysql_select_db($this->tablename, $this->con) or die(mysql_error()); //should be database name
 }

public function do_query($query){
 if(mysql_query($query,$this->con)){ //notice the change in this line 
         $message="Annuncio inserito correttamente!!";
         echo $message;
     }else{
         $message="Error insert data into DB: ";
         echo $message. mysql_error();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, code placed after `return` is not executing. This is never used:

```
mysql_select_db($tablename, $connect) or die(mysql_error());
```

So the database is never selected.

Secondly, you are connecting to your database twice per one query, while it should be once per whole http request.

Next thing, is that you use `mysql` lib, while there is newer called `mysqli`. Also you can try with PDO wrapper.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling DB::connect() which is static function you need to declare it as static such as

```
public static function connect(){

}
```

if you wanna call it inside the class, you have to do it like

```
Self::connect();
```

Comment: this is not the issue here

Comment: you can call a dynamic method statically in PHP please test it your self see if it gives error